# Can lognormal + constant be still considered lognormal?

Tags: distributions, terminology, lognormal-distribution

In one of my computations (result of GLM with some model values replaced with observations) I resulted with a distribution that is a lognormal distribution **plus** some constant. Can I still speak of lognormal distribution?

Again, this question is more about the statistical language and convention than about the statistics itself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think "shifted log-normal" is probably the normal terminology.